# Transforming/Rotating Part of Model Renderable

Tags: android, blender, arcore, sceneform

Can we create/design a 3D model with bones or vertices information (*.obj) in such a way that this info can be accessed through Sceneform and we can rotate that part?

Answer (score 0):

Moving the bones from Sceneform code is not supported at this time in ARCore, AFAIK.

You can attached nodes to the bones so that they move in time with the animation of the model contains the bones - for example a cup in a model's hand can move as the model is animated, but I don't think this is what you want.

Some people appear to have achieved what you are looking for in unsupported ways - see this example: https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/703

The problem with this is that it is unsupported so could change without notice.